# Dealing with RGB of the image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am developing one application . I have requirement like my application should detect particular color of the image . For e.g. if i want to detect the red color then i should see only the red areas of the image. I have tried this by following way :

**psudocode :**

First i have got the information of the each pixel of the image in the form of RGB using:

```
    for(int i=0; i < width; ++i)
{
    for (int j=0; j <height; j++)
    {
         byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * j) + i * bytesPerPixel;

        CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) /255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0)/255.0 ;
        CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0)/255.0 ;
        if (red>0.9 && red<1)
        {
            rgba[byteIndex]   =red*255;
            rgba[byteIndex+1] =green*0 ;
            rgba[byteIndex+2] = blue*0;
            count++;

        }

    }

}
```

then i am assigning this information to another image with null blue and green section hence i can only see the red areas of the image .It is working fine .

But the problem is with the for loop. I have to iterate for loop depend on the the height and width of the image . For e.g . If height of the image is 300 and width is 400 then is have to iterate the for loop for 300 * 400 =120000 times Which i don't think is a better way .So is there any way to do this efficiently ? is there any open source library to achieve this ?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you might try GPUImage and use either GPUImageRGBFilter to adjust the RGB values of an image, or GPUImageLookupFilter and map away the green and blue values.

Comment: That is very low amount of simple processing for current standards, and since you have to visit every pixel to do the filtering you are after, that is pretty much the complexity of the task (linear). This means you can only get some constant factor improvement by using some library that does things a tiny bit smarter. But, besides this, except this is a trivial application you are toying with, distinguishing colors in RGB is likely to produce bad results. Instead you should check for color spaces that dedicate a single channel to the hue, like HSB and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin optimizing your code. There are a lot of unnecessary operations and float/integer conversions there.

```
for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < width * height ; i ++ ) {
    NSUInteger red = rawData[i] ;
    if ( red > 230 ) {
        rawData[i+1] = 0 ;
        rawData[i+2] = 0 ;
    }
}
```